# Como remover linha que tem missing?

Tags: r

tenho uma base de dados que possui alguns missings (NA's), mas em apenas uma variável (uma coluna), e preciso retirar a linha inteira que tem o missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `subset` resolve isso de forma direta e mais clara, na minha opinião.
Isso pode ser feito em conjunto com a função `is.na` sendo aplicada a variável de interesse.

```
> data.frame(x=1:12, y=rnorm(12), z=c(TRUE, TRUE, NA))
    x           y    z
1   1  1.02572367 TRUE
2   2  0.03988014 TRUE
3   3 -0.33269252   NA
4   4  0.05357787 TRUE
5   5 -0.05166907 TRUE
6   6 -0.68981171   NA
7   7  1.14728375 TRUE
8   8 -0.76820827 TRUE
9   9 -0.45425148   NA
10 10 -0.27369393 TRUE
11 11 -0.12687725 TRUE
12 12 -0.38773276   NA

> df <- data.frame(x=1:12, y=rnorm(12), z=c(TRUE, TRUE, NA))
> subset(df, !is.na(z))
    x          y    z
1   1 -0.2223889 TRUE
2   2 -0.7398008 TRUE
4   4 -1.6382330 TRUE
5   5  1.2596270 TRUE
7   7  1.0555701 TRUE
8   8 -1.5904792 TRUE
10 10 -0.0942284 TRUE
11 11 -0.3278851 TRUE
```

E também é possível incluir mais regras no filtro.

```
> subset(df, !is.na(z) & x %% 2 == 0)
    x          y    z
2   2 -0.7398008 TRUE
4   4 -1.6382330 TRUE
8   8 -1.5904792 TRUE
10 10 -0.0942284 TRUE
```

Comment: A função `subset` não é recomendada para operações triviais como essa: *This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.*. Seria mais simples fazer `df[!is.na(df$z),]`

Comment: @Molx você tem um ponto, mas para mim legibilidade conta muito e o comando `subset` expressa melhor objetivo fim. Por esse motivo diversos pacotes novos do R específicos para manipulação de dados (dplyr, magrittr, ...) usam a *non-standard evaluation*.

Comment: Achei essa questão no SO discutindo essa questão do `subset` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Answer (score 5):

Para remover linhas sem dados em R, você deve a usar a função complete.cases().

Pro exemplo em um dataset {x}:

```
y <- x[complete.cases(x),]
str(y)
```

O complete.cases(x) é um vetor lógico que vai retornar TRUE para as linhas com dados e FALSE para linhas sem dados.

Comment: Entendo, mas está na base como NA e não vazio.

Comment: Você poderia usar a função  na.omit() .

Comment: Mas isso não remove a linha que tem o NA.

Comment: @WagnerJorge Se os seus dados fore NA o `complete.cases` deveria funcionar. Se não deu certo, adicione o resultado de `dput(dados)` à pergunta, talvez sejam strings vazias ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 5):

Considere o seguinte banco de dados:

```
> dados <- data.frame(
+     var1 = c(NA, 1),
+     var2 = c(1, NA)
+   )
>   
>   dados
  var1 var2
1   NA    1
2    1   NA
```

Você pode excluir todas as linhas que possuem pelo menos um missing usando o `na.omit`:

```
> na.omit(dados)
[1] var1 var2
<0 linhas> (ou row.names de comprimento 0)
```

Ou excluir todas as linhas que possuem missing (NA) em alguma variável:

```
> dados[!is.na(dados$var1),]
  var1 var2
2    1   NA
> dados[!is.na(dados$var2),]
  var1 var2
1   NA    1
```

Para verificar se um elemento do vetor é `NA`no R, usamos a função `is.na`:

```
> is.na(NA)
[1] TRUE
> is.na(1)
[1] FALSE
```

Para de fato remover os casos missings do data.frame, você precisa sobre-escrever:

```
dados <- na.omit(dados)
```

Answer (score 5):

Você também pode usar a função `filter` do `dplyr`:

Criando dados de exemplo (tomando como base os dados do Daniel):

```
dados <- data.frame(var1 = c(NA, 1, 3), var2 = c(1, NA, 3))
```

Carregando o `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
```

Remove `NA`s apenas da coluna `var1`

```
dados %>% filter(!is.na(var1))
```

Remove `NA`s apenas da coluna `var2`

```
dados %>% filter(!is.na(var2))
```

Para remover todos `NA`s, use `na.omit()` mesmo. Você pode encaixar na cadeia de piping facilmente:

```
# remove todos NAs
dados %>% na.omit
```

Answer (score 0):

Também pode-se usar a função `drop_na` do `tidyr`:

Dados:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(NA, 1:4), 
  y = c(1:4, NA)
)
```

Códigos:

```
library(tidyr)

drop_na(df_1) # para remover NA de todo o banco de dados

#  x y
#1 1 2
#2 2 3
#3 3 4
```

e

```
drop_na(df_1, x) # para remover NA apenas de `x`

#  x  y
#1 1  2
#2 2  3
#3 3  4
#4 4 NA
```