# Como salvar uma planilha de Excel a partir do R sem linhas em branco?

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Estou trabalhando com uma base de dados grande e que tem algumas linhas com IDs em branco. E eu quero salvar **somente as linhas sem ID em branco** em um arquivo de Excel.

Considerando que os IDs estão na primeira coluna da minha matriz, eis o que estou fazendo:

```
k <- which(is.na(Dados[,1]))
if (length(k) > 0) Dados <- Dados[-k,]
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("Pasta\\Nome.xls")
writeWorksheet(wb,data=Dados,sheet=1,header=TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Não sei por que, mas a planilha resultante ten todo o conteúdo da matriz Dados **mais tantas linhas em branco quantos eram os IDs em branco**.

Por exemplo, se a matriz Dados tinha 1000 linhas e 5 IDs em branco, eu fiquei com uma matriz com 995 linhas, mas a planilha resultante de Excel está ficando com as 995 linhas da matriz Dados **mais 5 lihas em branco no final**!

Considerando que eu preciso enviar uma planilha **xls** (não xlsx) **sem linhas em branco**, como posso resolver isso?

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: A variável `id` é uma string,  número...? Se você disponibilizar parte do banco de dados com `dput(head(dados))` ajudaria a esclarecer.

Comment: Se `id == NA`, então você pode filtrar seu *data frame* antes de salvar em Excel. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87730/como-remover-linha-que-tem-missing/87872#87872 . Ou usar `na.omit()`

Comment: Isso se `id == NA`. Pode ser que `id == ""`, por exemplo. Como o AP não especificou o que significa id em branco, não temos como adivinhar.

Comment: Vamos lá: ID é uma coluna numérica, com algumas células em branco. As duas primeiras linhas do código que postei são a filtragem do data.frame. E o problema era muito mais esquisito, pois, como teste eu substituí o filtro das duas primeiras linhas por ```k <- which(Dados[,2]==5)``` e ```Dados <- Dados[k,]``` e o resultado foi uma planilha de Excel com as linhas que têm 5 na segunda coluna no topo e todas as outras linhas abaixo.

Comment: Mas a matriz Dados era formada a partir de comandos e operações sobre outras matrizes. Como teste, eu apliquei o ```is.na``` em um passo mais para trás e deu certo, o problema foi resolvido. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pelas sugestões.

Comment: Para não deixar dúvidas: ID em branco significa NA mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Você inicialmente deve limpar deu data frame para posteriormente poder exporta-lo. Há diferentes maneiras de fazer isto, aqui apresentarei 3.

- Usando o pacote `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
nome_seu_dataframe <- nome_seu_dataframe %>%
  dplyr::filter(id != is.na(id))
```

- Usando o  pacote `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
nome_seu_dataframe <- nome_seu_dataframe %>%
  tidyr::drop_na(id)
```

- Usando o pacote `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nome_seu_dataframe <- data.table::data.table(nome_seu_dataframe )
nome_seu_dataframe <- nome_seu_dataframe [id != is.na(id)]
```

Ao aplicar o pacote `data.table` seu quadro passará a classe *data.table*. Se necessário retornar a *data frame*, realize:

```
nome_seu_dataframe <- as.data.frame(nome_seu_dataframe)
```

- Usando função residente `na.omit()`

```
nome_seu_dataframe <- nome_seu_dataframe %>% 
  na.omit()
```

---

Perceba que usei o pipe `%>%` em todas as opções. Ele é um operador do pacote `dplyr`, mas não necessariamente você precisará dele para proceder a remoção de `NA`.

Por exemplo:

```
library(tidyr)
nome_seu_dataframe <- tidyr::drop_na(nome_seu_dataframe, id)
```

---

Exemplo com *toy data*.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = c(seq(1,9,1), rep(NA, 4), 
                        seq(10,20,1),rep(NA, 3)),
                 V = rnorm(n = 27))

df2 <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(id != is.na(id))

df3 <- df %>% 
  na.omit()

library(tidyr)
df4 <- df %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na(id)

df5 <- tidyr::drop_na(df, id)

library(data.table)
df6 <- data.table::data.table(df)
df6 <- df6[id != is.na(id)]
df6 <- as.data.frame(df6)
```

Note que `df2`, `df3`, `df4`, `df5` e `df6` são iguais.